# Combinatorial proof for an identity about Stirling cyclic numbers

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

Solving through Lovász' *Combinatorial Problems and Exercises* I found an exercise asking me to prove two identities:

$$ \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \brace k} (x)_n = x^n $$
$$ \sum_{k = 0}^n \left[ n \atop k \right] x^k = x^{(n)}$$

(Notation note: I'm using [Pochhamer symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol), brackety ones are [cyclic Stirling numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) and curly ones are [partition Stirling numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind))

First one yields itself to a combinatorial proof, basically a combinatorial interpretation of the fact that every function can be ''transformed'' into a surjection if we restrict its codomain.

I was able to prove second one using generating functions, but I was unable to find a combinatorial proof. Due to obvious analogies between two identities (writing powers like a sum of falling factorials/ writing rising factorials like a sum of powers) I'm curious is there a combinatorial proof to the second identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I give one in [this previous math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162151/stirling-numbers-of-the-first-kind-a-direct-derivation). (Apparently you can't close a question as duplicate when there's a bounty on it?)

Comment: It's weird, I just started reading your blog post about Polya's enumeration theorem, so if I just waited a little bit longer with that bounty... :D