# Sum of all products of $k$ members of the set $\{1, 2, 3, \cdots, n\}$

Tags: combinatorics

How can I get a closed form for the sum of all products of $k$ distinct members of the set $\{1, 2, 3, \cdots, n\}$? I can see that for $k = 2$, the answer is $$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n-1}\sum\limits_{j = i+1}^nij$$
and this can be solved for an explicit formula. Is there a way to get this for arbitrary $k$?

Comment: It's the coefficient of the $(n-k)$'th degree term of $(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+n)$, but I don't think that helps much.

Comment: There's an answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1928394/closed-formula-for-the-sums-sum-limits-1-le-i-1-i-2-dots-i-k-le-n-i). I'm flagging the question as a duplicate, but I predict that I'm wrong, and will have to apologise - it's been one of those days! (This comment will shortly self-destruct ... as indeed will I, at this rate.)

Comment: @Arthur: actually that proves the answer is given by a Stirling number of the first kind.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio While it does help in looking up references, it does not help the concrete calculation. That problem remained unchanged after my comment. That's what I meant.

Comment: But a lookup at Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) does. Stirling numbers can be computed in a efficient way since they fulfill a great number of combinatorial identities.

Comment: @Arthur In fact, your comment is in fact how I even arrived at this question in the first place, as I was trying to figure out what the $(n-k)$th degree term is.